Cannot stepi into ecall in xv6
I am on the traps lecture of the 2023 version of the course. Following the instructions here tell me that I can stepi into the ecall instruction and see the jump to trapframe.
This does not seem to happen and it automatically jumps to ret. This answer asks for the same problem and the solutions suggest to use the newlib version of riscv64 compiler.
Thus, I installed the binutils-riscv64-unknown-elf_2.34-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb and gcc-riscv64-unknown-elf_10.2.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb packages which provide me with riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc with newlib support (newer versions seem to be built with the --without-newlib flag)
However, on running gdb-multiarch, I still can't step into the ecall function. I am on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. Is this something to do with ubuntu, or the fact that I am using gdb-multiarch instead of riscv64-unknown-elf-gdb? For some reason I can't seem to be able to find this online and my system is too frail to build any binaries so any leads on finding this will be helpful.

"step" or "stepi" ? They're two different gdb commands that have different effects, and your question seems not to clearly distinguish which you are using...

@PeterMaydell resolved, it is stepi that I am asking for

@AthaSSiN I'm having the same problem. How did you solve it?

I wasn't able to (by resolved i meant resolving @PeterMaydell 's question)

I don't know why you can't stepi it, but you can solve it by setting other breakpoint by b *$stvec
